# Unit testing UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, unit-testing, uilocalnotification, xctest, uiapplication

I am writing a framework that wraps `UILocalNotifiations`, and in the processes of writing unit tests for it. It's actually more of a functional test, but whatever.

So, the test I am trying to write is:

```
func testAlertManagerCanRegisterLocalNotifications() {

    let manager = Manager()
    manager.alerts = DummyAlerts

    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    let scheduledNotifs = app.scheduledLocalNotifications ?? []
    XCTAssertEqual(scheduledNotifs.count, manager.alerts.count)
}
```

Given that the manager synchronously schedules `UILocalNotifications` when the `alerts` property is mutated, this test should pass .. but it doesn't.

The root cause here is that the tests don't have the necessary permissions to schedule notifications, and I have no idea how am I suppose to allow the test app these permissions? After all, there is no UI involved.

**The Question:**

Is it possible to force the test app to have the necessary `UIUserNotification` permissions?

Comment: Of course, one solution is to mock the `UIApplication` object, but trying to find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You probably figured it out by now, but if you have your dummy alerts set to fire immediately it will not show in your `scheduledNotifs`. If instead you delay the alerts they will be in there.

Comment: No, they are set properly to a date in the future. The problem is with permissions, as mentioned in the question... I haven't figured it out yet :(

Comment: I was able to get to work by having a test to register notifications first, then a test to create a notification

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get to work by having a test to register notifications first, then a test to create a notification

```
func testNotificationRegister() {
    manager.registerForUserNotifications()

    let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
    XCTAssertTrue(settings != .None)
}

func testCreateNotification()
{
    let conf = common.createMockConference()
    manager.createNotifcationFromConference(conf, date: NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(30))
    XCTAssertTrue(UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications?.count > 0)
}
```